# PHP - check SSL certificate of the request

Tags: php, ajax, ssl

Is it possible for PHP to obtain the certificate of the request, and in particular the website name on the certificate and the CA?

I want to check that a call to my PHP file can only be made from my website via an AJAX call. Like this:

1. User logs onto my website and then uses https for subsequent interaction
2. User loads a page `https:// domain/mypage.php`
3. `https:// domain/mypage.php` has an AJAX call to `https:// domain/getinfo.php`

in getinfo.php I want to check the certificate details of the request to ensure that the request was made from my website, *i.e. not from a direct hit on the URL, or using a scraping tool.*

Possible?

Comment: Short answer: no. It doesn't matter what you do, it will always be possible to spoof the request so it looks like it came from Ajax. To be honest with you I can't even flesh out how this certificate approach would work at all - the same certificate would be used for all requests, Ajax or not, and unless you are requiring a client certificate (which is a total PITA for your users) the certificate you would be looking at will always be the server-side one, which obviously tells you nothing. Consider websockets, this will tell you a lot more.

Comment: The *server certificate* would ensure the identify of the server. Since your server is already receiving the request, I'm pretty sure you can be sure that your server is really itself. What are you trying to protect against here?

Comment: I'm trying to ensure that the calls to my getinfo.php originate from my website and not from someone trying to steal my (very expensive) data by just hitting the URL.  So I'd rather not give people a URL that they can access and get the data back in JSON format, I'd like to make it as difficult as possible, and at least rule out them getting it from the getinfo.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to ensure that the calls to my getinfo.php originate from my website and not from someone trying to steal my (very expensive) data by just hitting the URL.

You mean you want to ensure that *calls to your `getinfo.php` originate from a client that is visiting your website*? That's kind of an important distinction. "Your site" doesn't originate requests, *the client visiting the site* is. And whether or not the client still has your site open when it's sending the request is impossible to detect, each request looks exactly like any other.

You *could* require the client to send a token in the request which he must have gotten when opening your site. Typically that's a cookie and/or session id. Without a valid cookie/session, you won't answer the client.

That still makes it perfectly possible to scrape the data without actually opening your page, just make one request to get the cookie and another to get the data.

For all intents and purposes, if the API/site is public, so is the data. If you really want to protect it, you'll have to require user authentication and be careful who you're giving those accounts to. That also enables auditing and possible banning of users which appear to scrape your data.

Answer (score 0):

another way would be one-time GET/POST tokens, like you save your tokens along with a validity period and then you give the script the token and the script calls the site using https://example.com/getinfo.php?t=token for example
you give the client your data and delete the token so nobody can use the token that is used already.

also in any case you seem to be callive over SSL, which is good and better keep it because over HTTP the token no matter whether it's get or post is completely visible, so if an attacker shuts the connection and then tries to get the URL it's bad.

also any kind of malware could do the same because after transport the data (the token and even your "info") lies most likely unencrypted in the RAM, so it could be picked up without anyone noticing.